# Add script on head section without module

Tags: 7

I have a google add script Which I want to integrate on the head section. How can I add the script to the head section on drupal 7 without any module and info file? Script is below:

```
 (function () {

        var _onload = function(){

            if (document.readyState && !/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)){setTimeout(_onload, 10);return}

            if (!window.__adroll_loaded){__adroll_loaded=true;setTimeout(_onload, 50);return}

            var scr = document.createElement("script");

        };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter html.tpl.php and add your script in head.

Just alter html.tpl.php file from theme folder. If its not present copy it from 
drupal/modules/system folder.

Also you can use Js Injector module: https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector

Hope this will help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Add it your theme instead.

[html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x) would be the correct template to use.

Answer (score 0):

Add html.tpl.php (if not in theme folder) file in theme template folder and add this script to the file.

Answer (score -1):

I would place this script in external js file and insert it with "drupal_add_js" function in template file.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/file.js', array('type' => 'external','scope' => 'header','group' => JS_THEME,'every_page' => TRUE,'weight' => -1,));
```